# How to specify a config file for Mongod process

Tags: mongodb, config, homebrew

When running `mongod` I receive the non-critical error

```
[HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Failed to obtain address information for hostname flimflamjims-MacBook-Pro.local: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

This problem is well documented on stack overflow and solutions typically suggest editing `/etc/hosts` to specify an address of `127.0.0.1`. This does indeed resolve the issue however as an alternative I would like to specify a config file.

As per Homebrew's instructions I have tried running `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`. After running the command the process hangs with no logs being printed to the terminal.

`mongod.conf` was created automatically by Homebrew and its contents are:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

When I remove `mongod.conf` from `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/` and again run `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` I receive the error:

```
Error reading config file: No such file or directory
try 'mongod --help' for more information`
```

So it seems that `mongod.conf` is at least being accessed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't want logs in a file then remove whole 'systemLog' section, because destination, path and logAppend settings are used when you are logging to a file. If you want logs in stdout then remove all of them from the config file. Just removing the log file path will throw error.

Comment: Amazing - thanks very much. Yeah I misunderstood what was happening; I falsely assumed the process was hanging due to lack of output on the command line but really it was because logs were being saved in the file specified above.As soon as I figure out how to mark your answer as 'correct' I shall do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your configuration the logs will go to the log file mentioned in the `systemLog.path`. If you remove only the `systemLog.path` from the config file, it will thrown error as it won't be able to find the path for log file. Because `systemLog.destination` says log to `file`, you must specify `systemLog.path` as well. In case, you want logs be sent to stdout then you need to remove `systemLog.destination` and `systemLog.path` both.